# Oracle Query - to sum up the balances on some criteria

Tags: oracle

Can someone please help me to solve this .. I need to write oracle query to sum up the balances by by REF and REFERENCE_ID

Below are some criteria,

MultiValue can start with 1, 2, 3 and it will have any number of Subvalues from 1 to n...
Now PROPERTY field value is available only for MultiValue=1 and SubValue=1.. 
we have consider same PROPERTY property field for that multivalue set.

e.g for MultiValue 1 PROPERTY=BALANCE and Multivalue =2 PROPERTY = INTEREST etc...and need to sum up the balances
by REF and REFERENC_ID

Also, need to separate BALANCES amouts and INTEREST amount and PENALTY amount.

Here is some sample data... Any help is appreciated.. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Here is the sample output for first two ids..

[image]

Comment: What do you have at the moment and what is the problem with it? What output do you expect?

Comment: To repeat previous comment: Show us what you have tried and provide a sample of  results you want because it's hardly understandable from your explanations

Comment: Thanks a lot for response. Updated the post with sample output. I tried separating the multi values  and then union all. but its not working.. i am trying with ROW_NUMBER over partition by, But very new to this concept so facing challenge. Please help.

Comment: Please post data (and code) as [formatted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text, not as images. Images are not searchable, cannot be copied to create test data, and are not always available - some users have them blocked, some use screen readers, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill in the missing propery values with an analytic `first_value()` function call (or max, min, etc.):

```
select reference_id, multivalue, subvalue, code,
  first_value(property) over (partition by reference_id, multivalue) as property,
  ref, amount
from your_table;

REFERENCE_ID   MULTIVALUE   SUBVALUE       CODE PROPERTY R     AMOUNT
-------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------- - ----------
BILL121220PBD8          1          1      10001 BALANCE  a    1061.08
BILL121220PBD8          1          2      10001 BALANCE  b    5395.89
BILL121220PBD8          1          3      10001 BALANCE  c    4043.07
BILL121220PBD8          1          4      10001 BALANCE  d    4100.22
BILL121220R2HL          2          1      10001 INTEREST e   60487.88
BILL121220R2HL          2          2      10001 INTEREST e   60487.88
BILL121220R2HL          2          3      10001 INTEREST f  526631.51
...
```

Then you can use that as a subquery (as an inline view or CTE) to form the basis for your grouping:

```
select reference_id as bill_reference, property, ref as repay_ref,
  sum(amount) as repay_amount
from (
  select reference_id, multivalue, subvalue, code,
    first_value(property) over (partition by reference_id, multivalue) as property,
    ref, amount
  from your_table
)
group by reference_id, property, ref
order by reference_id, property, ref;

BILL_REFERENCE PROPERTY R REPAY_AMOUNT
-------------- -------- - ------------
BILL121220PBD8 BALANCE  a      1061.08
BILL121220PBD8 BALANCE  b      5395.89
BILL121220PBD8 BALANCE  c      4043.07
BILL121220PBD8 BALANCE  d      4100.22
BILL121220R2HL INTEREST e    120975.76
BILL121220R2HL INTEREST f    526631.51
...
```

(I retyped the reference IDs from your image to make up the test data, but couldn't be bothered to retype the individual ref's too. One of the reasons it's preferred to have text in questions rather than images.)

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to aggregate the amount by REF or REFERENCE_ID? If so, you should use `group by` clause.

For example, if you want to sum up the amount for each type of REF:

```
select REF, SUM(AMOUNT)
  from BALANCE_TBL
 group by REF
```